# How can I install a CA cert on my Samsung Nexus?

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

I have the cert as a `.cer` file on my Mac, and my phone is connected via USB. How can I install the cert on my device?

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file with an extension of .crt and place it in your SD card /download folder.

Put the SD card back into your device (or remount it, if internal) and navigate to SETTINGS > SECURITY & PRIVACY > INSTALL CERTIFICATE FROM SD CARD.

Hopefully that ought to do the trick, else try this [online Certificate Installer tool](http://www.realmb.com/droidCert/) - it gives you a link that you can navigate to using the Android web browser and install the certificate.